# Function that divides money with regard to the smallest denomination

Tags: javascript, comparative-review

I'm writing a function `divideMoney` that takes the value of a sum of money and divides it according to some percentages, then rounds each division to the nearest [denomination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denomination_(currency)).

For example:

```
//divideMoney(sum, percentages, denomination);

divideMoney(102, [0.5, 0.30, 0.20], 0.25);
```

This should divide the sum of $102 to 3 divisions, first is 50% ($51), second is 30% ($30.6) and the third is 20% ($20.4).

But because the smallest accepted denomination is the quarter ( `0.25` ), so $30.6 should be $30.50 instead, and $20.40 should be $20.50 as well. So the expected result is `[51, 30.5, 20.5]`.

Here is what I tried

**Original Code**

```
function divideMoney(sum, percentages, denomination) {
    var result, diff, resultSum;
    result = [];
    diff = 0;
    percentages.forEach(function (percent) {
        var div, fraction, mod;
        div = (percent * sum) + diff;
        fraction = div - Math.trunc(div);
        if (fraction > 0) {
            mod = fraction % denomination;
            diff += mod;
            div -= mod;
        }
        result.push(div);
    });
    resultSum = result.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 0);
    if (resultSum < sum) {
        result.push(sum - resultSum);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Update** (fix rounding)

```
function divideMoney(sum, percentages, denomination) {
    var result = [], remainder = sum, part, i;
    for(i = 0; i < percentages.length - 1; i++) {
        part = percentages[i] * sum;
        if (part % 1) {
            part = Math.round(part/denomination)*denomination;
        }
        remainder -= part; 
        result.push(part);
    }
    result.push(remainder);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work as expected? It sounds like it's not doing what it should.

Comment: **I think** it works well in many straightforward cases, however I'm not sure.

Comment: Add more unit tests and cover boundary conditions.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see in your code you do things with denomination and modulus, from the way I read your question it was like "it divides properly but doesn't handle denomination properly"

Comment: @Pimgd would you please give a test case that shows the improper handling of denominations ?

Comment: @KeyBored I thought you didn't handle it at all, but you do, so no problem here.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the method: when a primarily computed percentage does not match denomination, it's always decreased to the next one down. Shouldn't be rather increased/decreased to the closer one, like it usually apply when rounding?

Comment: @cFreed you are right, I fixed that.

Comment: @KeyBored please refrain from editing/adding code in your questions in the future if some answers have already been posted, as it can invalidate them. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

I can make infinite money (well, as much as will fit in a javascript number) with your code!

```
var money = 10;
while(true){
    money = divideMoney(money, [3, 0], 1)[0];//muhahahahah infinite money
}
```

Which divides the money like so: 1 for me, 1 for myself, 1 for I, none for you. 1 for me...

I'd recommend in this case to fall back on relative percentages: that is, sum the percentages and then set the cut to be the percentage of the summed percentage. So 10, 5, 5 = 20 total, 10/20 = 0.5, 5/20 = 0.25, so it's 0.50, 0.25, 0.25.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case I always assume that the provided inputs are valid, so I don't need to validate the inputs.

Comment: The `percentages` array will always contain values between 0 and 1 (exclusively), and their sum will be always 1.